# Combining web.config files

Tags: windows, include, web-config, http-status-code-404

Need some help combining these if you can, please.

One is to allow .html and .htm files to act like .asp files for some includes and the other is for custom 404 pages.

I've tried all sorts of variations, but everything apart from using the files separately gives me a '500 - Internal Server Error' message.

web.config 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<add name="htmlinc" path="*.html" verb="*" modules="ServerSideIncludeModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
<add name="htminc" path="*.htm" verb="*" modules="ServerSideIncludeModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

web.config 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultPath="/404.htm" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
<remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
<error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.htm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="On">
<error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.htm" />
</customErrors>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Check parent web.config files and look for issues cause by inheritance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<add name="htmlinc" path="*.html" verb="*" modules="ServerSideIncludeModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
<add name="htminc" path="*.htm" verb="*" modules="ServerSideIncludeModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultPath="/404.htm" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
<remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
<error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.htm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="On">
<error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.htm" />
</customErrors>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```